# How to submit two topologies from same main method of same jar in Storm cluster

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper, apache-storm

I am having 1 Zookeeper, 1 Nimbus and 2 Supervisors and I submitter a jar which two topologies to be submitter via StormSubmitter via a single main method

```
public static void main(String arg[])
{
.....
Config conf=new Config();
StormTopology aTopology = ATopologyBuilder.buildTopology(zkHost).createTopology();
StormTopology bTopology = BTopologyBuilder.buildTopology(zkHost).createTopology();
StormSubmitter.submitTopology("A", conf, aTopology);
StormSubmitter.submitTopology("B", conf, bTopology);
.....
}
```

Once I submit this jar in "storm jar" after starting storm nimbus, storm supervisors, storm ui. My current main method is working fine on the node-1 but it is not displaying on supervisor.

But when i Try the same steps for wordcount program. It is executing on both node-2 and is displaying on Storm UI.

Please help me to display the submitted topologies in the storm ui.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By changing my code as below and copied my jar into inputjar location.It is now submitting to storm cluster and displaying on the UI

```
Config conf = new Config();
conf.setDebug(true);
conf.setNumWorkers(20);
String inputjar="C:/storm/bin/Main.jar";
System.setProperty("storm.jar",inputjar);
StormTopology aTopology = ATopologyBuilder.buildTopology(zkHost).createTopology();
StormTopology bTopology = BTopologyBuilder.buildTopology(zkHost).createTopology();
StormSubmitter.submitTopology("A", conf, aTopology);
StormSubmitter.submitTopology("B", conf, bTopology);
```